# Sections in UITableView not showing properly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a problem with `UITableView` sections. I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate table and I've provided `sectionNameKeyPath:` on initialization.

Basiclly I have a table view with one section but when user taps on cell it is changing one core data attribute and should create second section. I think I've accomplished this but...

When I tap on the first cell it creates new section above (this is how it should be) but when my first tap is on another cell it creates section at the botton of table view. You can preview this on screenshots below:

[image]

Here are some Table View delegate methods from my app:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[_fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

And my question is: **How to manually provide section order?**

Comment: You can't manually order the section. Instead try reordering the array returned by `[[_fetchedResultsController sections]` using `sortUsingComparator:`/`sortUsingSelector:` or any such sorting method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example solution was pretty straight - adding one `NSSortDescriptor` to existing one in `NSFetchedResultsController` sort descriptors array.

So now, fetched data is firstly sorted by section and then it is sorted alphabetically.